# Can packer download and cache external files?

Tags: caching, gentoo, packer

I have a [packer project](https://github.com/moaxcp/gentoo64) for gentoo which downloads the iso through packer and the stage3 file in a script. The iso is cached by packer and I would like to get the stage3 cached as well. This way the stage3 is not downloaded every time the box is built.

Is there an easy way to have packer download the stage3 file and cache it in the same way the iso file is cached?